# Custom close reason for questions that are not about academia

Tags: discussion

Maybe I am missing something, but we don't seem to have a close reason for questions that are wildly off topic. Do we need a custom close reason for questions that are clearly off topic here, which may or may not fit on another site. Maybe something like:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not about academia. It may fit on-topic at another site within the SE network, in which case please flag the question and suggest where you would like it to be migrated.

Comment: If I try to flag a post, I have the option “It is blatantly off-topic”. Is this not available via the regular vote-to-close options?

Answer (score 1):

I believe we have "off-topic"->leave a comment. This was implemented because several questions were closed just by being off-topic, without leaving any comment or explaining why it was off-topic.

I would vote against having a generic "off-topic" closing vote: voting to close is a privilege, it should be used with caution. If someone cannot state in a comment why this post is off-topic, then they probably should not cast a vote.